# What is different between Create and NewRecord?

Tags: go, go-gorm

According to the document and gorm repo's issue,
`db.Create` is insert record.
`db.NewRecord` is only check if current value has primary key or not. So do not insert record.

I wrote below this code.
But I could insert record with `db.Create` and `db.NewRecord`.

What's different between this two methods?

```
for _, v := range oneday.Onedays {
    if err := tx.Create(&v).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return model.ResOnedays{}, err
    }

    // Photos
    for i, pv := range v.Photos {
        res := tx.NewRecord(&pv)
    }

    // Tags
    for _, tv := range v.Tags {
        tx.NewRecord(&tv)
    }
}
```

Comment: You've read the docs, and explained the differences. What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out, `Create` creates a new row by issuing an `INSERT`.

`NewRecord` doesn't affect the database at all, it just returns `true` if the current value's primary key is unset, meaning it's a new record. This means calling `NewRecord` in void context, as you have done, is meaningless, since you're ignoring the return value.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of get it. But when I replaced `NewRecord` to `Create``//Photos` section, error occurred. `Duplicate entry for primary key`. Maybe `NewRecord` don't have `error object` so I can't handling error when transaction.

Comment: `NewRecord` returns true or false, no error. But in your example, you're ignoring the return value.  It makes sense that replacing `NewRecord` with `Create` would cause an error--because then you try to create the record twice.